# Переместить объект при клике на него

Tags: html, jquery

```
<div class="emoji-chat">
     <i class="em em---1"></i>
</div>
<script>
    $('.emoji-chat i').click(function() {
         $('#text').append(' '+this+' ');
    });
</script>
```

В объект `<div id="text"></div>` добавляется не элемент, на который кликнули, а **[object HTMLElement]**. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="emoji-chat">
     <i class="em em---1">test</i>
</div>
<div id="text"></div>
<script>
    $('.emoji-chat i').click(function() {
         $('#text').append($(this).clone());
    });
</script>
```